# VLC/python API methods not found in library libvlc.so.5

Tags: python, dll, vlc

I use [vlc bindings for python](https://wiki.videolan.org/Python_bindings/). Many of the API methods are not found. For example, using the method  `parse_with_options`:

```
> File "/home/alain/Audio/audioserver/media/vlc.py", line 2565, in
> parse_with_options
>     return libvlc_media_parse_with_options(self, parse_flag, timeout)   File "/home/alain/Audio/audioserver/media/vlc.py", line 5408, in
> libvlc_media_parse_with_options
>     ctypes.c_int, Media, MediaParseFlag, ctypes.c_int)   File "/home/alain/Audio/audioserver/media/vlc.py", line 254, in _Cfunction
>     raise NameError('no function %r' % (name,)) NameError: no function 'libvlc_media_parse_with_options'
```

The exception is raised here in `vlc.py`:

```
if hasattr(dll, name) and name in globals():
   ...
raise NameError('no function %r' % (name,))
```

`dll` is contructed as:

```
p = find_library('vlc')
try:
    dll = ctypes.CDLL(p)
except OSError:  # may fail
    dll = ctypes.CDLL('libvlc.so.5')
```

This fails because the method name is not found in the `dll`. Does somebody know how to install a version of `libvlc.so.5` that support more API methods? I searched for packages around VLC, I found that it exists a 3.0 version (my current version is 2.2.2), but I don't think it is related.

Comment: https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=138775

Comment: Thanks, that's the answer.